# Add files to my ListView using

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add the option to my application to add a directory with all the files in the directory into my `ListView` and because I'm checking each file before add to my `ListView` (my files are Wiresahrk files so I'm checking the file extension and if the are not pcap format I convert the file and then add) and I want to do it with separate Threads so I'm using `BackgroundWorker` and I need some help of how to do it:

```
private void btnAddDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
    string fileToAdd = string.Empty;
    List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = null;
    DialogResult dialog = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Editcap editcap = new Editcap();

        foreach (string file in SafeFileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            if (editcap.isWiresharkFormat(file))
            {
                filesList.Add(file);
            }
        }

        backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork +=
            (s1, e1) =>
            {
                foreach (string fileName in filesList)
                {
                    if (editcap.isWiresharkFormat(fileName))
                    {
                        if (editcap.isLibpcapFormat(fileName))
                        {
                            lv.Text = fileName;
                            lv.SubItems.Add(fileName);
                            lv.SubItems.Add("Waiting");

                            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                            {
                                lvFiles.Items.Add(lv);
                            });

                            lvFiles.Refresh();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        (s1, e1) =>
        {

        });

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding items in `backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event, do it in `DoWork`.

Otherwise you will get error `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control ___  accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

Change

```
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, fileToAdd);
```

To

```
lv.SubItems.Add(fileToAdd);
```

Also, You donot need to handle `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

Comment: i cannot find UserState under DoWork

Comment: It was typo. fileToAdd should be added, and not the userstate

Comment: OK i can see with the debugger that the files added to the ListView but cannot see this files in the ListView, maybe its because i have 2 columns ?

Comment: yes, i think you need to set DisplayMember to property name which must be displayed

Comment: Not so successful for me, can i have example ?

Comment: where are you adding listviewitem to listview?

Comment: lvFiles.Items.Add(fileToAdd) crash with cross threading error

Comment: ok, make new method that accepts string parameter, and in that method, add calls to GUI (lvFiles.Add ,etc). Call that method using Invoke.

Comment: OK see my update, i successfully  add the first file but after Refresh() crash again with cross Threading

Comment: I donot see Refresh() method, but use Invoke/BeginInvoke to avoid cross thread exception.